# How to upload image from local system to azure blob storage in c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a image file from local system to azure blob storage using c#. Below is the code I am using:

```
string storageConnectionString = "<connection_string>";
CloudStorageAccount storageacc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageacc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("myblob");
container.CreateIfNotExists();

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("images");

using (var filestream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\11173.jpg"))
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(filestream);
}
```

I am trying to create container with name `myblob` which I can see is created. Inside it I create a blob with name `images` and then upload the image file in it. But I cannot see image file in it. Whats wrong in the above code. How can I upload image files into blob storage. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. What do you mean by you can’t see the file in the container? How are you checking it?

Comment: Since your code looks correct,did you check if the image file is existing in your local path

Comment: @GauravMantri It just shows images and there is nothing inside it.

Comment: Are you expecting `11173.jpg` inside `images` folder?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes you can say that or even `11173.jpg` inside `myblob` will also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try something like the following:

```
string storageConnectionString = "<connection_string>";
CloudStorageAccount storageacc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageacc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("myblob");
container.CreateIfNotExists();

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("images/11173.jpg");
blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpg";
using (var filestream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\11173.jpg"))
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(filestream);
}
```

Basically the code above saves `11173.jpg` as `images/11173.jpg`. Blob name is actually `images/11173.jpg`.

Or you could try something like:

```
string storageConnectionString = "<connection_string>";
CloudStorageAccount storageacc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageacc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("myblob");
container.CreateIfNotExists();

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("11173.jpg");
blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpg";
using (var filestream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\11173.jpg"))
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(filestream);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

After installing the recommended nuget pkg "Azure.Storage.Blobs" (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/),  following code worked in .NET core

```
       public void PersistPhoto(IFormFile fileToPersist, string saveAsFileName)
       {
            string connectionString= "Azure Storage Connection String";
            string containerName= "Azure Storage Container Name";
            BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);

            try
            {
                // Get a reference to a blob
                BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient(saveAsFileName);

                // Open the file and upload its data
                using (Stream file = fileToPersist.OpenReadStream())
                {
                    blob.Upload(file);                  
                }

                uri = blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
            }
            catch
            {
                // log error
            }
        }
```

The NuGet pkg "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" is now deprecated according to Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two things wrong.

1. Is **myblob** your container? GetContainerReference requires that you pass in the name of the container, not the blob name. I'm guessing the container name is **images**.
2. *GetBlockBlobReference* requires the path including filename within the container of the image (blob) you are attempting to upload.

It should be something like this:

```
string storageConnectionString = "<connection_string>";
CloudStorageAccount storageacc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageacc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images");
container.CreateIfNotExists();

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("11173.jpg");

using (var filestream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\11173.jpg"))
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(filestream);
}
```